# How do i display my results in the GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
#this picks a random number
def roll_dice():
    from random import randint
    for x in range(2):
        print(randint(1,6))
#this makes the GUI
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('first GUI')
root.geometry('500x500')
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
label = Label(app, text = 'Dice Simulator')
label.grid()
button1 = Button(app, text = 'Roll Dice', command = roll_dice)
button1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

I'm using this to simulate rolling two dice and display the results. This is my first project as a programmer and my first experience making a tkinter

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Why dont you add another `Label` or similar and write your result there?

Answer (score 0):

You want to always import modules at the top of your program, this way your code is easier to read.

To display your result from `roll_dice` you need to first at a text box where you can display the result. I am calling this box `output` You can accomplish this by doing:

```
output = Text(root, height=1, width=5) #create the output box
output.place(x=100,y=100) #place the output box at desire place on the UI
```

Now to display the result in the `output` box we can use the `insert` Tkinter function. Do the following:

```
output.delete('1.0', END)     #clears the output box
output.insert(END, randint(1,6))   #insert the result into the
```

With your code, it should look something like this:

```
def roll_dice():
    for x in range(2):
        output.delete('1.0', END)     #clears the output box
        output.insert(END, randint(1,6))   #insert the result into the output box
#this makes the GUI


root = Tk()
root.title('first GUI')
root.geometry('500x500')
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
label = Label(app, text = 'Dice Simulator')
label.grid()
button1 = Button(app, text = 'Roll Dice', command = roll_dice)
button1.grid()
output = Text(root, height=1, width=5) #create the output box
output.place(x=100,y=100) #place the output box at desire place on the UI

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Welcome to StackOverflow. I hope this is the answer you are looking for. Cheers

Comment: if you are going to use grid then use `row/column = number`. Gird is not meant to be used like pack. If you want to use a basic example like this then use `pack()` instead.